# Quicksort algorithm with random pivot in the middle of the array

Tags: java, algorithm, random, quicksort

i have to write a quicksort-algorithm with a random pivot so i created the following code:

```
public void quickSort(int left, int right)
{
    if(a.length == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Only one element.");
    }
    else
    {
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        if(right > left)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = left + rand.nextInt(right - left);
            int p = a[num];

            int tmp = a[r];
            a[r] = a[num];
            a[num] = tmp;
            num = r;
            r--;


            while(r > l)
            {
                while((l<right)&&(a[l]<=p))
                {
                    l++;
                }
                while((r > left)&&(a[r]>=p))
                {
                    r--;
                }
                if(l < r)
                {
                    tmp = a[l];
                    a[l] = a[r];
                    a[r] = tmp;
                }
            }

            if(a[l] > p) {
                tmp = a[l];
                a[l] = a[num];
                a[num] = tmp;
            }

            quickSort(left,l-1);
            quickSort(l+1,right);
        }

       }
    }
```

"a" is supposed to be an int-Array.
As you can see, as soon as I get my random pivot I swap it with the last element of the array so I don't get any problems with the algorithm, but I wonder if there is a possibility to let the pivot stay at it's random position and sort it without problems, nevertheless. 
Thx in advance.

Comment: What language is this?  It looks like Java.  If so, you should add a Java tag so people who watch that tag will see it.

Comment: [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) just needs a pivot value that can be anywhere in the array, so no need to swap the pivot to left or right.

Comment: Just wonder if your code could pass {1, 0}?

Comment: @antonio081014 tried that out, worked fine

Comment: @ChampSilver, cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Basically, we can make the inequalities stricter: change `a[l]<=p` to `a[l]<p` and `a[r]>=p` to `a[r]>p`.
This will help handle the case when there can be equal elements in the array, too, so you can get rid of the `l<right` and `left<r` conditions.

The pivot is not guaranteed to land at precisely position `l`, then, but still, `a[left...l]` will be `<=p` and `a[l+1...right]` will be `>=p`, which is just enough for the algorithm to work.

Here is a variation of your code that works.
The condition `if(l < r)` is modified to be `if(l <= r)`, and inside, `l++;` and `r--;` are added to skip the two elements we just swapped.
Also, the recursive calls are updated to `(left,r)` and `(l,right)`, since there is now no guaranteed position for the pivot element.

```
public void quickSort(int left, int right)
{
    if(a.length == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Only one element.");
    }
    else
    {
        int l = left;
        int r = right;
        if(right > left)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = left + rand.nextInt(right - left);
            int p = a[num];

            while(r > l)
            {
                while(a[l]<p)
                {
                    l++;
                }
                while(a[r]>p)
                {
                    r--;
                }
                if(l <= r)
                {
                    int tmp = a[l];
                    a[l] = a[r];
                    a[r] = tmp;
                    l++;
                    r--;
                }
            }

            quickSort(left,r);
            quickSort(l,right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So.. I changed the inequalitites like you said and got rid of the part which would swap the pivot to the end ("int tmp = a[r]....... r--;") and now im getting an endless loop - but i dont know why

Comment: @ChampSilver Added a working version of the code with no guaranteed position for the pivot element. Sorry, you were right: a few tweaks still remained to be done.

Comment: Thx alot for your effort, i worked alot on it too and got the exactly same code which makes me very happy right now :)